# Calculating index of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, matrices, finite-groups, modular-forms

Compute the index $[Γ(
1
)
′
:
Γ_0
(
N
)
′
]$

where $Γ(1)' := SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

$Γ_0(N)':= \{ \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
 \end{pmatrix} \in Γ(1)' : c \equiv 0 \mod{N} \} $

I'm basically stuck on how to get started.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what $c = 0 mod N $ means

Comment: Why have two people voted to close this question as "unclear"? It is sensible and very natural to ask what the index of a congruence subgroup is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume that $N=p^m$ is a prime power.

Consider $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. If $p\not\mid d$, then $dx+c\equiv 0\pmod {p^m}$ has a unique solution mod $p^m$ (for example with $x\in\{0,\ldots, p^m-1\}$). With such an $x$ we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\x&1\end{pmatrix}\in\Gamma_0'(p^m)$$
i.e. there are (at most, but by uniqueness of $x$ exactly) $p^m$ cosets in $\Gamma_0'(1)/\Gamma_0'(p^m)$.
However these cosets do not cover the case $p\mid d$ yet.
But if $p\mid d$ then necessarily $p\not\mid c$ and we can apply the reasoning above after multiplication with $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$. This gives us $2p^m$ cosets in total.

You can combine this using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find that the index in the general case is $2^rN$ if $N$ has $r$ prime divisors.